# How to start ROS2 node automatically after starting the system?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to make autostart of nodes in ROS2 at system startup? I tried through rc.local and nothing good came of it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333968/how-to-start-ros2-node-automatically-after-starting-the-system?/) by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We use systemd service with properly defined environment variables, works fine.
Example:

```
[Unit]
Description="Project daemon"

[Service]
Environment="ROS_DOMAIN_ID=42"
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/project/install/lib:/opt/ros/dashing/lib"
Environment="PYTHONPATH=/opt/project/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/ros/dashing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/"
Environment="AMENT_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/project/install:/opt/ros/dashing"
    
ExecStart=/opt/ros/dashing/bin/ros2 launch --debug project_bringup project.launch.py
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Originally posted by [Dmitriy](https://answers.ros.org/users/45566/dmitriy/) with karma: 78 on 2019-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2021-08-11**:
Can you tell us more infos about that? For instance: where do you put that file? And why did you specify `WantedBy` ?

**Comment by [Lar](https://answers.ros.org/users/133931/lar/) on 2023-02-13**:
Can someone please explain how can I know what to put in the "Environment"? I tried to put in the paths I get when running "printenv | grep -i ROS" (I get much longer paths for some reason) but I still get "Package not found" when running the service.